# Homogeneous line bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

I came across a notation while I am reading in an article but I am not famialr by what it means. And it is like the following:

Let $B$ be the upper triangular subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb C)$ and define the character $\chi $ on $B$ by 
$$\chi^n\begin{bmatrix}
  t & s  \\
  0 & 1/t 
\end{bmatrix}=t^n$$   Now let $\begin{bmatrix}
  x & y  \\
  z & t 
\end{bmatrix}\in SL(2,\mathbb C)$ then Gram-Schmidt process we have 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
  x & y  \\
  z & t 
\end{bmatrix}=k\begin{bmatrix}
  \sqrt{ |x|^2+|z|^2} & 0 \\
 0 & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ |x|^2+|z|^2}} 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & \eta  \\
  0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$ Where $\eta =\dfrac{y\bar x+t\bar z}{ \sqrt{ |x|^2+|z|^2}}$ and $k\in SU(2)$.

Writing $\chi=\chi^n$ then we have $SL(2,\mathbb C)\times_\chi\mathbb C \stackrel{\Theta}{\cong}SU(2)\times_{\chi_{S^1}}\mathbb C$.

Can someone explain to me what is going on? What does $\times_\chi$ mean? And why this works like this?

Comment: Can you add the link of the article ? I don't claim I can answer but maybe context can help :)

Comment: Thanks N.H I asked the same question here and I got some answers https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197619/understanding-the-homogeneous-space-sl2-mathbb-c-times-mathbb-c-cong-su2